# What are the fruits?

Tags: word

There are two fruits, each with 6 letters in the name. Both fruits use letters exclusively from a set of 7 letters.

⁃The name of one of the fruits uses 6 out of the 7 letters, using each of the 6 letters distinctly once.
⁃The name of the other fruit uses only 3 of the 7 letters (but repeats most of those letters at least once). Half of the letters that are repeated, are repeated exactly twice.

Comment: The first fruit seems to be a bit too unconstrained: I'd expect there to be several six-letter fruit with no repeated letters that share 2 or 3 letters with the second fruit, no matter what the second fruit is. Indeed I see two distinct perfectly fine solutions below. Playtesting one's own puzzles is difficult, since you can't avoid knowing what the puzzle setter intended, but I've found that stepping away from the puzzle for a day or so, and then carefully rereading the text catches quite many "bugs" like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two fruits are:

> "Orange" and "Banana" using the set of 'O', 'R', 'A', 'N', 'G', 'E', 'B'.

> Orange uses all distinct letters while in Banana, most of the letters are repeated except for B. Out of the two letters that are repeated (N and A), one is repeated twice.

Answer (score 1):

The set of letters are:

> D,u,r,i,a,n,b

The two fruits are

⁃The name of one of the fruits uses 6 out of the 7 letters, using each of the 6 letters distinctly once.

> Durian

⁃The name of the other fruit uses only 3 of the 7 letters (but repeats most of those letters at least once). Half of the letters that are repeated, are repeated exactly twice.

> Banana

Comment: This works too.

Comment: Some other (rarer, but no less valid) options for the second one: DAMSON, KORLAN, IYOKAN, TANGOR.